# What's the correct usage of matplotlib.mlab.normpdf()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, distribution, gaussian

I intend for part of a program I'm writing to automatically generate Gaussian distributions of various statistics over multiple raw text sources, however I'm having some issues generating the graphs as per the guide at:

[python pylab plot normal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138085/python-pylab-plot-normal-distribution)

The general gist of the plot code is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

meanAverage = 222.89219487179491    # typical value calculated beforehand
standardDeviation = 3.8857889432054091    # typical value calculated beforehand

x = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
pyplot.plot(x,mlab.normpdf(x,meanAverage,standardDeviation))
pyplot.show()
```

All it does is produce a rather flat looking and useless y = 0 line!
Can anyone see what the problem is here?

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you made a few small but significant errors.  You either are choosing your x vector wrong or you swapped your stddev and mean.  Since your mean is at 222, you probably want your x vector in this area, maybe something like 150 to 300.  This way you get all the good stuff, right now you are looking at -3 to 3 which is at the tail of the distribution.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 19):

If you read documentation of [matplotlib.mlab.normpdf](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.normpdf), this function is deprycated and you should use [scipy.stats.norm.pdf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) instead.

> Deprecated since version 2.2: scipy.stats.norm.pdf

And because your distribution mean is about 222, you should use `np.linspace(200, 220, 100)`.

So your code will look like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

meanAverage = 222.89219487179491    # typical value calculated beforehand
standardDeviation = 3.8857889432054091    # typical value calculated beforehand

x = np.linspace(200, 220, 100)
pyplot.plot(x, norm.pdf(x, meanAverage, standardDeviation))
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I asked this question a very long time ago, so I am not surprised it has changed. Thanks for the update, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I see that, for the `*args` which are sending meanAverage, standardDeviation, the correct thing to be sent is:

```
mu : a numdims array of means of a

sigma : a numdims array of atandard deviation of a
```

Does this help?

Comment: Annoyingly, all object types I've thrown at it have'nt worked... 

There must be a simpler way than this.