# How to draw normal distribution given mean and standard deviation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I am looking to draw a two dimensional normal distribution using numpy given the mean and the standard deviation of 30. I am relatively new to numpy. I have read the numpy.random.multivariate_normal function but dont have a clarity on what the covariance matrix represents and how to represent the standard deviation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pylab plot normal distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138085/python-pylab-plot-normal-distribution)

Comment: By 2d do you mean you want to plot two normal distributions on the same plot? Or a multivariable Guassian dist? A covariance matrix simply represents the covariance between each element in the row vs the column. Here are some good docs on `multivariable_normal` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html

Comment: I am given a two dimensional array (340, 340). The mean of the distribution is (170, 170) and the standard deviation is 30. I have no clue as to how to create the covariance matrix and the visualize the curve.