# How to solve "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: scipy.stats.norm.pdf" warning?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am using matplotlib in my Python code. I got following warning: 
`xxx.py:88: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: scipy.stats.norm.pdf
  y = 100 * mlab.normpdf(bin_middles, mu, sigma)*bin_width` 
I was wondering what the issue is, so I can solve it and avoid warnings.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation tells us about [`matplotlib.mlab.normpdf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.normpdf)

> Deprecated since version 2.2: scipy.stats.norm.pdf

This translates into: Do not use this function any more, use [`scipy.stats.norm.pdf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) instead.

Hence a previous code like

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
mu = 0
sigma = 1
y = mlab.normpdf(x, mu, sigma)
```

should now read

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

x = np.linspace(-3,3)
mu = 0
sigma = 1
y = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)
```