# How to project certain values from the graph on the axis in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a normal distribution curve in Python using matplotlib. I followed the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138308/7665691) in the post [python pylab plot normal distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138085/python-pylab-plot-normal-distribution) in order to generate the graph.

I would like to know if there is a way of projecting the mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma and the mean values on both the x-axis and y-axis.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**
Image for explaining projection
[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVCRF.png).

In the image, I am trying to project the mean value on x and y-axis. I would like to know if there is a way I can achieve this along with obtaining the values (the blue circles on x and y-axis) on x and y-axis.

Comment: if you have the positions of the point you want to plot, you can do `ax.plot([x0, x0, 0], [0, y0, y0], 'k-')` for each projected point

Comment: What do you mean by projecting? Can you give an image example?

Comment: Hey @jdhao, I have edited the post and have added an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script shows how to achieve what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

mu = 2
variance = 9
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)

x = np.linspace(mu - 3*sigma, mu + 3*sigma, 500)
y = stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xlim([min(x), max(x)])
ax.set_ylim([min(y), max(y)+0.02])

ax.hlines(y=max(y), xmin=min(x), xmax=mu, color='r')
ax.vlines(x=mu, ymin=min(y), ymax=max(y), color='r')

plt.show()
```

The produced plot is

[image]

If you are familiar with the properties of normal distribution, it is easy to know intersection with x axis is just `mu`, i.e., the distribution mean. Intersection with y axis is just the maximum value of y, i.e, `max(y)` in the code.