# How to draw a histogram that follows a specific distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

[This question is somehow related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138085/python-pylab-plot-normal-distribution) but it is slightly different]

I need to get a histogram (with np.histogram) that follows either a normal, or F or gamma distribution that peaks at a specific value x given an average and a standard deviation.

So far, I have tried things such as:

```
  s = np.random.normal (avg, stddev, nbsamples)
  h = np.histogram (s, nbbins)
```

but this clearly does not work as it returns in h[0] the profile of the standard distribution (in the example above for a normal distribution).

My question is, how can I get the histogram with a given average and standard deviation to peak at one specific value x?